Unable to retrieve data from External Table with Azure Data Explorer ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
We have created an external table in our ADLS Gen 2 from our Azure Data Explorer as follows:
.create-or-alter external table ourtable (
        SourceKey:decimal,
        SupporterId:long
        )
kind=storage
dataformat=parquet ('abfss://xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/Path/filename.parquet;managed_identity=system')
with (
    folder='storageaccount/container',
    docString=```Information    ```
)

When attempt to view the data in the container/folder using the following:
external_table("ourtable")
| take 10

I get the following error:
Query execution has resulted in error (0x80131500): Partial query failure: 0x80131500 (message: 'Service request failed.
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Headers:
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 9cca9d71-d01e-007b-163c-1a425a000000
x-ms-client-request-id: 17cad00d-6fa6-4f75-a609-2ad772510971
x-ms-version: 2022-11-02
x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2024 11:15:55 GMT
: ', details: 'Source: Azure.Storage.Blobs
Service request failed.
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Any thoughts on what might be causing the error?

when you create the external table, you should provide a path for a container/directory, and not a specific parquet file
i.e. instead of:
'abfss://xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/Path/filename.parquet;managed_identity=system'
try specifying:
'abfss://xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/Path;managed_identity=system'
you should also make sure the permissions you've assigned to the managed identity are for that path, and not for a specific file.
if you only need to query a specific file, you can use the externaldata operator

Hi @Yoni L. thanks for getting in touch. I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.
I have set the following permissions on the Storage account - 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' and 'Storage Queue Data Contributor'. Are there any other permissions you think I should set?

IINM (this may not be 100% accurate) you need to set the Storage Blob Data Reader at the container level

L, thanks again for getting in touch, I will try and add Storage Blob Data Reader, however I would have thought that 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' would provide enough permissions??

Hi @Yoni L. You were correct. I needed to set the Storage Blob Data Reader at the container level. Thank you very much.
